# Единая авторизация

Tags: vkontakte-api, авторизация, youtube, gmail

На сервисах, типа `Gmail`, `vk.com` есть интересная система авторизации. При авторизации на `Gmail` происходит автоматическая авторизация на `youtube` по тому же мейлу, a когда авторизуешься на `vk.com` - на сайтах, где есть их `API` с формой для ответа, также сразу авторизован. Собственно, в какую сторону смотреть, что-бы подсмотреть принцип реализации такого подхода?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите получить в результате. Возможно стоит посмотреть OpenID. А лучше более подробно описать практическую проблему, которая возникла перед вами.

Comment: Авторизовавшись на сайт site1.com, а через некое время зайти на сайт site2.biz (у которых общая база пользователей), этот сайт (site2.biz) узнавал пользователя, тем самым сразу его авторизировал (минуя процесс ввода логина/пароля).

Comment: база именно общая? Т.е. одна база на два сайта? Или же имеется в виду что совпадают логины и пароли?

Comment: В перспективе речь идёт о множестве сайтов, которые (дочерние) через API могут организовать автоматическую(/полуавтоматическую) авторизацию. Т.е. если на родительском или на одном из дочерних сайтов, где подключен родительский API авторизоваться, используя логин/пароль, произойдет авторизация (при посищении) других сайтов из данного API-семейства. Т.е. не нужно повторно вводить логин/пароль. А база она общая, да.